# easiest script in AJAX with JQuery doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i m tring to learn using ajax but no one of my script work:

```
<script>
function test()
{   
    var par = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    alert ("i m here!"+par);
    $.Ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ProvaAJAX.php",
      data: "par="+par,
      success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Select Item:**

```
<select id="nazione_pr" class="select-registrazione" onchange="prova()" name="nazione_pr">
```

**Input item:**

```
<input id="nome" class="input-text" type="text"name="nome">
```

**ProvaAJAX.php**

```
<html>
<?php
    echo "Test success". $_POST['par'];
?>
</html>
```

....  i think this script should be ok but my server doesn't think this...
when i change the "select" value the "i m here" alert box appear but after nothing happen...

Comment: @mplungjan: $("nome").val() will be $("#nome").val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many issues

- It's  lowercase a in $.ajax
- data: {"par":par},
- you use jQuery so use var par = $("#nome").val();
- your function is called something else than what you call it

Hit F12 in IE or Chrome or install firebug in Firefox and hit F12 there too to see the console

```
<script>
$(function() { // when the page has loaded
 $("#nazione_pr").on("change",function() {
    var nazione = $(this).val(); // the select's value
    var par =$("#nome").val();  // the textfield's value
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ProvaAJAX.php",
      data: {"par":par,"nazione":nazione},
      success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does "Still not working" mean. Please post error messages from console and from calling `ProvaAJAX.php?par=test` from the location bar

Comment: solved, my framework suck, it autochange my /provaAJAX.php path

Answer (score 0):

please change onchange="prova()" to onchange="test()"

```
<script>
    function test()
    {   
       var par = document.getElementById("nome").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProvaAJAX.php",
            data: { par:par,fun:"test" }
            }).done(function( data ) 
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            });

    }
    </script>
```

and php file:-

```
if($_REQUEST['fun'] == "test")
{
 echo $_REQUEST['par'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Launch AJAX request.
            $.ajax(
                {
                    // The link we are accessing.
                    url: jLink.attr( "href" ),

                    // The type of request.
                    type: "get",

                    // The type of data that is getting returned.
                    dataType: "html",

                    error: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - error()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
                    },

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - beforeSend()" );
                    },

                    complete: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - complete()" );
                    },

                    success: function( strData ){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - success()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( strData );
                    }
                }                           
                );

            // Prevent default click.
            return( false );                    
        }
        );
```